# Where are the lucidatypewriter fonts?

Tags: 12.04, fonts

In older Ubuntu versions and older X11s in general, there used to be the fonts

```
-b&h-lucidatypewriter-* ...
```

I have installed `xfonts-base`, `xfonts-75dpi`, `xfonts-100dpi` but still I cannot find any matching font with `xfontsel` or `xlsfonts`. To be sure: I want the bitmap fonts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was necessary to reboot to make the installed fonts visible to `xlsfonts`. Logout was not enough.

Comment: Actually you just need to restart the X server I believe.  In my case, I was using vnc so I just needed to kill and restart vnc.